Using Alembic Exporter in Unity freezes dynamic mesh
I’m trying to export a mesh that is being animated with code from Unity to an Alembic file so I can render it in Blender. However, as soon as the Alembic Exporter starts recording (in play mode) the mesh is frozen in it’s initial state (at least it appears that way in the viewport and the resulting Alembic file reflects the same frozen object). If I disable the Alembic Exporter or keep it from recording the mesh animates normally.
I’ve also tried creating a custom Alembic exporter script and use that but the same thing happens no matter what I do. I’ve tested if the Update function is called but even with the Alembic exporter this seem to be the case (it’s called throughout, so it’s not that the main thread is locked up). It’s just that its effects are no longer visible in the viewport or the Alembic file.
I’m pretty new to Unity so there’s probably a simple solution or I’m not understanding something basic about the exporter.
Here is the code for the mesh GameObject:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine;

public class CustomMesh : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Mesh mesh;
    private Vector3[] vertices;
    private int[] triangles;

    void Start()
    {
        mesh = new Mesh();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;

        CreateShape();
        UpdateMesh();
    }

    void CreateShape()
    {
        // Define vertices (positions of the mesh points)
        vertices = new Vector3[]
        {
            new Vector3(0, 0, 0), // Vertex 0
            new Vector3(0, 1, 0), // Vertex 1
            new Vector3(1, 1, 0), // Vertex 2
            new Vector3(1, 0, 0)  // Vertex 3
        };

        // Define triangles (the order of vertices that make up each triangle face)
        triangles = new int[]
        {
            0, 1, 2, // First triangle
            0, 2, 3  // Second triangle
        };
    }

    void UpdateMesh()
    {
        mesh.Clear();
        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.RecalculateNormals(); // For proper lighting
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Example: Move vertex 0 over time
        vertices[0] = new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(Time.time), 0, 0);
        //Debug.Log("Update.");
        
        // Apply changes to the mesh
        UpdateMesh();
    }
}

And here is the code for the Alembic exporter:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Formats.Alembic.Exporter;

public class AlembicCustomExporter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AlembicExporter alembicExporter;  // Drag the exporter component here
    public float exportDuration = 5f;        // How long the animation is
    public float frameRate = 30f;            // Frames per second for export

    private bool isExporting = false;
    
    void Start()
    {
        // Start capturing the animation in a coroutine
        StartCoroutine(CaptureAnimation());
    }

    IEnumerator CaptureAnimation()
    {
        isExporting = true;

        float timePerFrame = 1f / frameRate;  // Calculate time interval for each frame
        float startTime = Time.time;          // Track the starting time
        float currentTime = 0f;
        int frameCount = 0;

        // Begin recording with Alembic
        alembicExporter.BeginRecording();

        // Loop for the duration of the export (in seconds)
        while (currentTime < exportDuration)
        {
            // Wait for the next frame
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

            // Wait for the next frame time based on the frame rate
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(timePerFrame);

            // Update the elapsed time and frame count
            currentTime = Time.time - startTime;
            frameCount++;

            Debug.Log($"Frame {frameCount} captured at {Time.time}s");
        }

        // End the recording after the duration has passed
        alembicExporter.EndRecording();
        isExporting = false;

        Debug.Log("Alembic export completed.");
    }
}

Here are my settings for the GameObject:


Is this a skinned mesh? Or could you in general show us all relevant settings for the alembic exporter? I guess you refer to the sinus animation of the vertex[0] right? (on first glance I thought animation refers to an animator - maybe this would be more a deformation)

In specific is Static MeshRenderers enabled?

I've added my settings for the GameObject including the Alembic exporter component. StaticMeshrenderers seems to be enabled.
Yes, normally vertex[0] moves back and forth, which is what I see without the exporter when I'm in play mode.
Could it be because the MeshFilter is initialised on the start frame and the Alembic exporter expects it to be present when it starts (before the first frame)?

That might indeed be related .. have you tried to delay the beginning of the capture by a frame or two? (yield return null;) You can btw directly make private IEnumerator Start() and if you don't need the debug log you could also just make it a yield return new WaitForSeconds(exportDuration); but I guess you did the loop more for checking that it isn't freezing entirely

CreateShape seems unnecessary .. you could already initialize these fields right away .. could even be static readonly. And then I would move the first mesh init into Awake to be sure it exists already

I've added a loop before the recording starts almost identical to the one after the recording starts except while (frameCount < 3). I've also tried with higher frameCounts to make sure everything was initialized. It now animates for these frames but freezes as soon as the recording begins.
